# next-auth email provider authorize type error

Tags: reactjs, authentication, next.js, next.js13, next-auth

i am completely new to Next.js. I had previously worked on the frontend with Next.js but this is my first time working on the backend and functionality. I have been stuck for about 4 hours on how to distinguish between email providers. I have two types of users, and I want to send emails according to their types. According to the documentation I read [here](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/providers/email#:%7E:text=Required-,id,-Unique%20ID%20for), it mentioned that we can distinguish using an ID, but when I give the ID, it is giving me this error
[image: Error]
**If you know any other way how I can distinguish between the two users and send them a magic link, then please let me know**
Auth.js

```
import { PrismaAdapter } from "@next-auth/prisma-adapter";
import type { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";
import EmailProvider from "next-auth/providers/email";
import { prisma } from "./prisma";
import { render } from "@react-email/components";
import { transporter } from "./mail";
import { NewUserEmail } from "../components/emails/new-user";
import { ActivationLink } from "../components/emails/activation";
import { error } from "console";

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
  pages: {
    signIn: "/sign-in",
  },
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
  },
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET!,
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      id: "google-provider",
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID as string,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET as string,
      allowDangerousEmailAccountLinking: true,
    }),
    EmailProvider({
      id: "user-type1",
      from: process.env.EMAIL_FROM,
      sendVerificationRequest: async ({ identifier, url, provider }) => {
        const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
          where: {
            email: identifier,
          },
          select: {
            emailVerified: true,
          },
        });

        const html = !user?.emailVerified
          ? render(NewUserEmail({ url }))
          : render(ActivationLink({ url }));

        const mailOptions = {
          from: provider.from as string,
          to: identifier,
          subject: "Verification of Email",
          html,
        };
        try {
          await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
        } catch (err) {
          console.log("ERROR while sending", err);
        }
      },
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async session({ token, session }) {
      if (token) {
        session.user.id = token.id;
        session.user.name = token.name;
        session.user.email = token.email;
        session.user.image = token.picture;
      }

      return session;
    },
    async jwt({ token, user }) {
      const dbUser = await prisma.user.findFirst({
        where: {
          email: token.email,
        },
      });

      if (!dbUser) {
        if (user) {
          token.id = user?.id;
        }
        return token;
      }

      return {
        id: dbUser.id,
        name: dbUser.name,
        email: dbUser.email,
        picture: dbUser.image,
      };
    },
  },
};
```

package.json

```
{
    "name": "saas",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "next dev",
        "build": "prisma generate && next build",
        "start": "next start",
        "lint": "next lint",
        "stripe:listen": "stripe listen --forward-to localhost:3000/api/webhook"
    },
    "prisma": {
        "seed": "ts-node --compiler-options {\"module\":\"CommonJS\"} prisma/seed.ts"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@heroicons/react": "^1.0.6",
        "@lemonsqueezy/lemonsqueezy.js": "^1.2.5",
        "@next-auth/prisma-adapter": "^1.0.7",
        "@prisma/client": "^5.4.1",
        "@radix-ui/react-avatar": "^1.0.4",
        "@radix-ui/react-checkbox": "^1.0.4",
        "@radix-ui/react-dropdown-menu": "^2.0.6",
        "@radix-ui/react-icons": "^1.3.0",
        "@radix-ui/react-label": "^2.0.2",
        "@radix-ui/react-separator": "^1.0.3",
        "@radix-ui/react-slot": "^1.0.2",
        "@radix-ui/react-switch": "^1.0.3",
        "@radix-ui/react-tabs": "^1.0.4",
        "@react-email/components": "^0.0.7",
        "@stripe/stripe-js": "^2.1.7",
        "@supabase/supabase-js": "^2.39.3",
        "@tremor/react": "^3.10.1",
        "@uploadthing/react": "^6.1.0",
        "axios": "^1.5.1",
        "bcrypt": "^5.1.1",
        "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
        "class-variance-authority": "^0.7.0",
        "clsx": "^2.0.0",
        "crisp-sdk-web": "^1.0.21",
        "framer-motion": "^10.16.4",
        "lemonsqueezy.ts": "^0.1.7",
        "next": "13.5.4",
        "next-auth": "^4.23.2",
        "next-themes": "^0.2.1",
        "nodemailer": "^6.9.6",
        "posthog-js": "^1.100.0",
        "raw-body": "^2.5.2",
        "react": "^18",
        "react-dom": "^18",
        "react-fast-marquee": "^1.6.2",
        "react-icons": "^4.11.0",
        "react-snowfall": "^1.2.1",
        "react-spinners": "^0.13.8",
        "resend": "^1.1.0",
        "stripe": "^13.9.0",
        "tailwind-merge": "^1.14.0",
        "tailwindcss-animate": "^1.0.7",
        "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
        "uploadthing": "^6.1.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/bcrypt": "^5.0.0",
        "@types/bcryptjs": "^2.4.4",
        "@types/node": "^20",
        "@types/nodemailer": "^6.4.11",
        "@types/react": "^18",
        "@types/react-dom": "^18",
        "autoprefixer": "^10",
        "eslint": "^8",
        "eslint-config-next": "13.5.4",
        "postcss": "^8",
        "prisma": "^5.4.1",
        "tailwindcss": "^3",
        "typescript": "^5"
    }
}
```

the error is: "Argument of type '{ id: string; from: string | undefined; sendVerificationRequest: ({ identifier, url, provider }: SendVerificationRequestParams) => Promise; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EmailUserConfig'.
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'id' does not exist in type 'EmailUserConfig'".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to assign a property `id` to the `EmailProvider` configuration object. The `EmailProvider` from `next-auth` doesn't have an id property in its configuration object.

To identify between different types of users and send them different magic links, you can handle this logic inside the `sendVerificationRequest` function by checking user attributes that you store in your database.

Try to modify your `sendVerificationRequest` as for your need like following,

```
sendVerificationRequest: async ({ identifier, url, provider }) => {
  // Fetch the user from the database
  const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
    where: {
      email: identifier,
    },
    select: {
      emailVerified: true,
      userType: true, // assuming you have a userType or similar field in your User model
    },
  });

  // Determine which email template to use based on the user's type
  let html;
  if (user) {
    if (!user.emailVerified) {
      html = render(NewUserEmail({ url }));
    } else if (user.userType === 'type1') {
      html = render(YourType1EmailTemplate({ url })); // replace with your actual type1 email component
    } else if (user.userType === 'type2') {
      html = render(YourType2EmailTemplate({ url })); // replace with your actual type2 email component
    } else {
      html = render(DefaultEmailTemplate({ url })); // replace with your default email template
    }
  }

  // Define the mail options
  const mailOptions = {
    from: provider.from as string,
    to: identifier,
    subject: "Verification of Email",
    html,
  };

  // Send the email
  try {
    await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("ERROR while sending", err);
  }
},
```